# Docker run command on Bluemix does not allow to set environment variable correctly

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

When I try to create a docker container with either

```
cf ic run -e AUTHORIZED_KEYS="`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`" --name ssh-test -d busybox
```

or after setting the environment variables with

```
docker run -e AUTHORIZED_KEYS="`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`" --name ssh-test -d busybox
```

I always get back following error message, which is not reported when running the command on the local docker host:

```
FATA[0001] Error response from daemon: Error creating container 
{'space_guid': u'guid', 'name': u'ssh-test', 'tenant_name': u'tenant',
'image': u'guid', 'security_groups': None, 'flavor': u'1', 'id': None,
'tenant': u'tenant'}: too many values to unpack
```

I've tried a few things and the easiest way to trigger the error message is following command, containing two equals (`=`) characters:

```
cf ic run -e "AUTHORIZED_KEYS='ABC=='" --name ssh-test busybox
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this use-case not supported?

Comment: if the environment variable exists the proper way to set it is `-e AUTHORIZED_KEYS="cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"`  you don't need to include the ` mark inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

following this Docker documentation ENV variables need to be included in double quotes
https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

This is probably why the output of your cat command is exploded giving 'too many values to unpack'.
Probably on local execution it is checked and 'corrected' but during network packing/unpacking omitting double quote is not supported.

Anyway, according to Docker documentation I linked above, you could try to add the value of your public key directly in Docker file, where you can specify ENV variables like you do through console: using Dockerfile will allow you to manage in a more comfortable way the value of your public key.